# GAE JSP not compiling with jar in WEB-INF

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, compilation

This may be a simple issue but i am spinning my wheels at this point. I am using the google app engine, and I have a simple jsp that has the following snippit in it

```
<%@page import="main.java.psbdom.*" %>
....
<%= PS_STRINGS.LABEL %>
```

and then i have a jar in the WEB-INF/lib dir that has this contents

```
$ jar -tvf psbdom-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
     0 Tue Feb 07 19:11:36 EST 2012 META-INF/
   124 Tue Feb 07 19:11:34 EST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Feb 03 20:42:30 EST 2012 main/
     0 Fri Feb 03 20:42:30 EST 2012 main/java/
     0 Fri Feb 03 20:42:30 EST 2012 main/java/psbdom/
     0 Fri Feb 03 20:42:30 EST 2012 main/java/psbdom/constants/
     0 Fri Feb 03 20:42:30 EST 2012 main/java/psbdom/data/
     0 Fri Feb 03 20:42:30 EST 2012 main/java/psbdom/user/
   602 Tue Feb 07 19:11:32 EST 2012 main/java/psbdom/constants/PS_STRINGS.class
```

this is the PS_STRINGS class

```
public class PS_STRINGS 

    {
        //public static final String 
        public static final String LABEL = "LABEL";
    ...
    }
```

and i get this error

```
An error occurred at line: 9 in the jsp file: /admin/addConcept.jsp
PS_STRINGS.LABEL cannot be resolved to a type
6: <title>Add Concept</title>
7: </head>
8: <body>
9:  <%= PS_STRINGS.LABEL %>
```

i am really baffled as to what i am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the "import.*" wrong, The wildcard (import *) only applies to classes, not to sub-packages.

Try

```
<%@page import="main.java.psbdom.*, main.java.psbdom.constants.*" %>
```

Comment: however i'm not sure this will solve my issue as i had previously tried putting the entire class path in the import and that had not worked either. However i will still give this a go when i get a chance.